# How to write to a file in python without adding a new line except at certain place?

Tags: python, file-writing

I want to write to a file without adding a new line at the iterations of a for loop except the last one.

Code:

```py
items = ['1','2','3']
with open('file.txt', "w") as f:
        f.write('test' + '\n')
        for t in items:
         f.write(t + '\n')#i didnt know i could add the '\n'
        f.write('test' + '\n')#here for it to work
        for t in items:
         f.write(t + '\n')
        f.write('end')
```

Output in the file:

```py
test
1
2
3
test
1
2
3
end
```

Output I want in the file:

```py
test
123
test
123
end
```

I am new to python, so sorry for any inconstancies.

Comment: ...and add '\n' at the start of the arguement to the second f.write('test' + '\n') and in f.write('end')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items = ['1','2','3']
with open('file.txt', "w") as f:
        f.write('test' + '\n')
        for t in items:
         f.write(t)
        f.write('\n'+'test' + '\n')
        for t in items:
         f.write(t)
        f.write('\n'+'end')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is code that should solve your issue

```
items = ['1', '2', '3']
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('test \n')
    for i in items:
        f.write(i)
    f.write('\n')
    f.write('test \n')
    for i in items:
        f.write(i)
    f.write('\n')
    f.write('end')
```

Notice that you just want to iterate through the list items in the for loop, then add a separate write statement for the new line before the next 'test'
Also it's best to just use the escape character \n for newline within the single quotes instead of attaching it with the '+' symbol.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the list to become a string follow this template

num = ['1', '2', '3']
str1 = ""

for i in num:
str1 += i

print(str1)

output:
123